# What is the best place to save singular data in Asp .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-config, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Asp .Net MVC web app which uses Entity Framework to save and get data. Some sections of website need to be updated yet they are made of singular sections (text), no collections, no repeating structures. For them using EF and saving one row (or a small Key/Value table) of data to database seems a burden to me.

One way I can do this is to use AppSettings section of Web.Congfig, but I doubt about security doing that.

What is the most proffesional way to implement for such a case?
XML file? if so... where in folder structure?

Or good old Entity Framework still is best way to go with one table of Key/Value pairs?

Thanks.

Comment: Will your application be deleting or updating this data when it's running or is it static data?

Comment: Good not so old EF still the best way, imho. You load the key/Value from global asax and, as you are smart, you have a controller action to reload them in case they change. So when you save the database, you also save the configuration. Moving the application become, always imho, easier.

Comment: There will be updating, no deletes @englishbob.

Comment: Thanks for the info bogac, this considered I agree with @tschmit007 I would still use EF. If you already have EF in place, I'd say it's no more hassle than the other options and keeps everything in one place.

Unfortunately EF does not provide a second level cache, it's a backlogged feature at present. Although you can roll your own or go for an open source option...

https://efcache.codeplex.com/

Comment: Caching EF data seems a nice idea. I already take advantage of dependency injection. Would it be beneficial to cache on top DI? Or does it work hassle free with dependency injection? @englishbob

Comment: Any caching option should just extend EF and work hassle free with any dependency injection implementation you have.